# Convert Date Field to String Field Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, expression

I have a Date field in an ArcGIS file geodatabase feature class called "DateTemp1." I created a new text field called "DateTemp2" and want to calculate that based on the DateTemp1 field, but I am getting a unicode error.

TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'unicode'

```
 arcpy.CalculateField_management("all_reports.gdb/lsr_reports1", "DateTemp2", "datetime.datetime.strftime(!DateTemp1!, '%Y%m%d')", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

Comment: No that did not work. I edited my question to include the error message. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered the [Convert Time Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/convert-time-field.htm) tool? (ArcGIS 10.3+)

Comment: Your chosen solution works well if you need to control the exact format, but keep in mind that the error you received originally is caused by the fact that `CalculateField` passes the date field as a string into Python. In other words, you could have simply used the expression `!DateTemp1!` and you would have gotten a string formatted using the default expression (usually MM/DD/YYYY).

Comment: You're right I tried that as well and it did work. The string was formatted MM/DD/YYYY as you stated. I do want the final string to be in the format YYYYMMDD. Using Convert Time Field it keeps the hours and minutes (YYYYMMDDHHMM). Now I am just trying to figure out how to dump the HHMM and create a new field, but that is another question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `"datetime.datetime.strptime( !DateTemp1! , '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y%m%d')"` as your expression:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("all_reports.gdb/lsr_reports1", "DateTemp2", "datetime.datetime.strptime( !DateTemp1! , '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y%m%d')", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

**NOTE** you will need to change the `'%d/%m/%Y'` from in `strptime( !DateTemp1! , '%d/%m/%Y')` to match the current format of your existing date field

Comment: This works well too. I am going with this but I had to change the syntax to match the existing date field.     "datetime.datetime.strptime( !DateTemp1! , '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').strftime('%Y%d%m')"

Answer (score 2):

I looked into using the Convert Time Field tool as the poster suggested and it worked.

```
inTable  = "all_reports.gdb/lsr_reports1"
inputTimeField = "DateTemp1"
inputTimeFormat ="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss;AM;PM"
outputDateField = "DateTemp2"
arcpy.ConvertTimeField_management(inTable, inputTimeField, inputTimeFormat, outputDateField)
```